# How to access elements within dom-repeat in Polymer 3.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, dom-repeat

I have the following piece of code:

```
<dom-repeat id="template" items="{{chats}}">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.opened]]">
        <section id$="msg-[[index]]"></section>
      </template>
    </template>
</dom-repeat>
```

How do can I access section with id=msg-3 and set scrollTop to 999 upon being rendered?

I know that in polymer 1 the best practice was to bind to on attached and wait on a dom-repeat event with a debouncer this no longer works in polymer 3, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index number you can access the element with ;

```
let el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#msg-'+<index>);
```

Remember, if item not rendered due to your filter with  `dom-if`, you can not acces this element.

**EDIT**

In order to show on top  of the selected item;

```
let screenPosition = el.getBoundingClientRect();
window.scrollTo(screenPosition);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-access-elements-within-dom-repeat-in-polymer-30?file=index.js)

Comment: This is only a part of the solution, the other is to bind successfully on dom-repeat finishing rendering, dis' only possible with a debouncer.

Comment: @Max0999, It is quite easy if you could reach the dom-element. If you need I can add you over the same example

Comment: it is quite easy to say that it is quite easy, actually doing it might prove the opposite

Comment: @Max0999,  Actually, I am not sure what exactly you want with `set scrollTop to 999` But I guessed, you wanted to scroll to the element as it's at the top. Check the link whether you wanted this?